# Unable to load javascript without html in webview Android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load my local(`from assets folder`) `js` file into webview but it keeps on throwing error `Uncaught reference, method hello not found`. But when I try to load an `HTML` file in same way that works.

content of my js file:

```
function hello(p1, p2) {
    console.log(5 + 6);
    return p1 * p2;
};
```

I am loading this file into a fragment

```
webView = new WebView(getContext());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
                Log.d("test--test--test--resp", consoleMessage.message());
                return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.js");
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:hello(1,2)");
            }
        });
```

Can someone please point out what I am missing or how can I load `javascript` file properly without `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, got the answer after a few experiments. In webview if one wants to run/load `JS` file using `loadUrl` method without html the content of `JS` file should be within 
`<script></script>` tag.